# Javascript, translate date using array

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

Due to the language barrier I am unable to find an answer to a problem I'm having. 
Using 2 arrays in JavaScript I need to translate a date.

```
var months =['january','february','march','april','may','june','july','august','september','october'.'november','december'];
var weekday = ['sunday','monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday'];
```

Using this I am supposed to turn for example:

Mon Oct 28 2018 14:41:20 GMT+0100
into
Monday 28 October 2018

My apologies for this likely being a repost of a question that has been answered previously, but as I previously mentioned I was unable to find it.

Comment: If you're open to using libraries, try [MomentJs](https://momentjs.com/) and don't reinvent the wheel: `moment(myDate).format('dddd DD MMMM YYYY');`

Comment: You might be able to test the input strings with regular expressions. Regex may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need external **libraries** in order to achieve your **requirement**.

You just need to use some `Date` [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

```js
var months = ['january','february','march','april','may','june','july','august','september','october','november','december'];

var weekday = ['sunday','monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday'];

var date=new Date();

console.log(getDate(date));

function getDate(date){
   return [
     weekday[date.getDay()],
     date.getDate(),
     months[date.getMonth()],
     date.getFullYear()
   ].join(' ');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the type of answer I was looking for. However I cannot really use this, I started with jscript about a week ago so I don't know much yet.
I need to display the answer on the page using document.write. Is there a way you/I could change this code so it could do that? Thank you.

Comment: Please don't recommend using the built-in parser, see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results). Consider just reformatting the string *without* creating a Date object.

Answer (score 3):

Use moment.js

```
moment(new Date('Mon Oct 28 2018 14:41:20 GMT+0100')).format('dddd DD MMMM YYYY')
```

Comment: "Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info."

Comment: ```moment(new Date('Mon Oct 28 2018 14:41:20 GMT+0100'))..format('dddd DD MMMM YYYY')```

Comment: "[...] Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged [...]"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to vanilla `javascript` solution:

A simple solution (if you can forgo the exact full month name):

```js
var date = new Date("Mon Oct 28 2018 14:41:20 GMT+0100");

console.log(date.toDateString());
```

**Or**

Pass some `options` into `toLocaleDateString`:

```js
var date = new Date("Mon Oct 28 2018 14:41:20 GMT+0100");

console.log(date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", {
  weekday: 'long',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric'
}))
```

[Check MDN `Date` documentation here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)